# selectRowAtIndexPath does not scroll in to the correct position in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Im having around 80 items. if my selected index was 15(or less value) it scrolls to the correct position. But if selection index was 70 it does not scroll. but it has selected the row when i manually scroll. Does anyone has idea how to fix that?

```
-(void)select:(NSString*)selectedIndex {
    if(selectedIndex == nil){
        return;
    }
    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView*)view;
    if(tableView == nil) {
        return;
    }

    NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [self findIndexPath:selectedIndex table:tableView];

    if(nextIndexPath != nil && ![viewController isSelectable:[selectedIndex intValue]]){
        NSArray *indexPaths = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
        nextIndexPath = [self nextMoveUp:nextIndexPath :indexPaths];
    }
    if(nextIndexPath != nil) {
        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        if ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath] == nil) {
            // cell is not visible - scroll it into view
            [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
        }
    }
}

-(NSIndexPath*)findIndexPath:(NSString*)selectedIndex table:(UITableView*)tableView{
    NSArray *indexPaths = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    if(indexPaths == nil || [indexPaths count] == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = NULL;
    for (NSIndexPath *path in indexPaths) {
        if(path.row == [selectedIndex intValue]){
            return path;
        }
        lastIndexPath = path;
    }
    if(lastIndexPath != nil && lastIndexPath.row < [selectedIndex intValue]){
        [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
        return [self findIndexPath:selectedIndex table:tableView];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem.  In my case I was calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath (or selectRowAtIndexPath) before all the rows were defined, i.e. before cellForRowAtIndexPath had been called on all the rows.  My solution was to define a method to select the row and call it with performSelectorOnMainThread to delay until the first refresh was complete.