# scrollToRow(at:at:animated:) SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have `List` with 100 items 
I want to scroll to item number 20 
How can I achieve this in `SwiftUI`

Here is my simple ListCode

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {
                self.scrollToIndex(index: 20)
            }) {
                Text("Scroll To 20")
            }
            ForEach(0..<100) {_ in
                Text("Hello World")
            }
        }
    }

    func scrollToIndex(index: Int) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Earlier tried to find some solutions for this [answering here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58830883/9982386). Shortly: today (November 2019) I found no solutions, except using `ScrollView` or `UITableView` (making last `UIViewControllerRepresentable`)

**update** found [Apple Developer Forums thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/118485) with this question from September and there is still no answer

Answer (score 0):

With the new `ScrollViewReader` in iOS 14, you can simply do something like that:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            List {
                Button(action: {
                    self.scrollToIndex(proxy, index: 20)
                }) {
                    Text("Scroll To 20")
                }
                ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                    Text("Hello World").id(i)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func scrollToIndex(_ proxy: ScrollViewProxy, index: Int) {
        withAnimation {
            proxy.scrollTo(index)
        }
    }
}
```