# How to save List state for View in TabView SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a TabView in SwiftUI with tabs. When I scroll list from one FirstView and tap another tab, and switch back to FirstView, my List in FirstView automatically redraws and scrolls to top. How to fix that.

[enter link description here](https://gph.is/g/4w8mj0j)

This is FirstView

```
 var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(feed) { game in
                FeedCardItem(gameModel: game)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30, height: 400)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Новое сегодня"))
    }
}
```

This is TabView implementation

```
    TabView (selection: $currentTab) {
        FeedView().tabItem {
            Image(systemName: currentTab == 0 ? "house.fill" : "house")
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .imageScale(.large)
        }.tag(0)

        RecommendationsView().tabItem {
            Image(systemName: currentTab == 1 ? "gamecontroller.fill" : "gamecontroller")
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .imageScale(.large)
        }.tag(1)

        SearchView().tabItem {
            Image(systemName: currentTab == 2 ? "flame.fill" : "flame")
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .imageScale(.large)
        }.tag(2)

        NotificationsView().tabItem {
            Image(systemName: currentTab == 3 ? "bell.fill" : "bell")
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .imageScale(.large)
        }.tag(3)

        ProfileView().tabItem {
            Image(systemName: currentTab == 4 ? "person.fill" : "person")
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .imageScale(.large)
        }.tag(4)

    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
}
```

Comment: Provide some minimal code that can be run and debugged. It will help providing a quick answer.

Comment: @FelixMarianayagam added

Comment: That should do.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, and found this solution: https://kavsoft.dev/SwiftUI_2.0/Tab_Bar

Basically, you could just hide the content of one tab instead of replace it with another content view. I thought this solution is a little tricky but works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible via SwiftUI. The alternate to do this is to create the tabview in UIKit and use it in SwiftUI.

I have created a quick sample of how this can be achieved and how it solves your issue. Let me know if you have any other questions.

I have uploaded the code to GitHub.
https://github.com/subhan5/TabTest

In the uploaded code, the folder UITab contains the tabview created via UIKit. 
In ContentView, I convert the same as UIViewControllerRepresentable and use it.

Comment: Is this a bug? Apple did not provide for the proper operation of the Tabs?

Comment: Yes, Apple hasn't provided it for SwiftUI as of now.

Comment: But if I want to create very beautiful custom tabbar in SwiftUI, I can not use it while maintaining the state?

Comment: As of now, SwiftUI has this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible with the UITableViewConfigurator which is described here: [Scroll SwiftUI List to new selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57121782/scroll-swiftui-list-to-new-selection)

But of course...this uses UIViewControllerRepresentable....